# Mount : Permission Denied

Tags: solaris, mount, sparc

I am trying to mount a solaris sparc 5.10 dir over solaris sparc 5.11 like

root> mount S5.10Machine:/mydir /mydir

and I am getting

nfs mount S5.10Machine:/mydir permission denied.

I have given 777 permission on S5.10Machine:/mydir

Comment: This should work. How's it shared in  /etc/dfs/dfstab on S5.10Machine  ?  This is not really a programming question. Would be better in serverfault

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to mount nfs share, be sure that you have premittions in /etc/dfs/dfstab.

[man share](http://www.bga.org/~lessem/psyc5112/usail/man/solaris/share.1.html)

There is rw option, which set right to access.

And if you want to mount nfs share, right command will be:

```
mount -F nfs S5.10Machine:/mydir /mydir
```